# :ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> Hi I have 2 tables Employee & User table,  using employee table if i
>   deactive the employee it should be get deactivate in User also, but
>   when im tring this im getting an error, can any one tell me wre im
>   wrong.

employee_controller.rb

```
def change_status
    if params[:employee][:status] == "Abscond"
        params[:employee][:last_working_date] = params[:emp_last_date]
    elsif params[:employee][:status] == "Resigned" || params[:employee][:status] == "Internal Resignation"
        params[:employee][:resignation_date] = params[:emp_last_date]
    end
    params[:employee].delete(:entity_id) if params[:employee][:entity_id].blank?
    params[:employee].delete(:activate_reason) if params[:employee][:activate_reason].blank?
    if @user.present?
        @user.lock_access!
    end
    @employee.update_attributes(employee_params.merge!("updated_by" => current_user.id))
    respond_with(@employee)
end
```

User_controller.rb

```
 def change_status
    if @user.access_locked?
        @user.unlock_access!
    else
        @user.lock_access!
    end
    respond_with(@user)
end

if the employee get deactive means Abscond||resigned||internal designation means User should be get inactive, but using this only USer is getting in active not an employee...
Im trying to change the status from employee
```

Comment: only error show in this action ?

Comment: The error" econnrefused ...." Usually appear when your database is turned off. What database are you using?

Comment: Postgresql data base im using

Comment: yes when im trying to change the status of the employee it is not working but in user it is getting change